Integrating error function
When integrating
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx}$$
we can use the trick of letting
$$I = \int^\infty_{-\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx} = \int^\infty_{-\infty}{e^{-y^2}dy}$$
and then using $I^2$ after which you can switch to polar coordinates to get a final answer of $\pi$, which then implies that $I=\sqrt{\pi}$
The antiderivative has no expressions in terms of elementary functions of course, but what I'm confused about is why we can't define
$$I(t) = \int^t_{-t}{e^{-x^2}dx} = \int^t_{-t}{e^{-y^2}dy}$$
and use the same method of squaring $I(t)$

Can you express the square $[-t,t]\times[-t,t]$ nicely in polar coordinates? I can't.

@KurtG. it can complex to express a square in polar coordinates.

@Dan Lupu, as I said in the previous commemt, it is difficult to express the region in polar coordinate

$$I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$ So, the reason why we don't prefer $I(t)$ is it easier to express the region of $I$, that is $\{(r,\theta):0\leq\theta<2\pi,0\leq r\}$
